# Conflicting Spring schedules

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I've two scheduled tasks that run at different time intervals. The first task is scheduled to run every 5 seconds and the second task is scheduled to run every 10 minutes.

```
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTask {

    @Autowired
    private taskService taskService;

    @Scheduled(every 5 second)
    public void scheduleTaskA() {
        taskService.taskA()
    }

    @Scheduled(every 10 minute)
    public void scheduleTaskB() {
        taskService.taskB()
    }
}

public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    void taskA(){
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("callStoreProcedure1"); 

        if(query.execute()) 
            query.getSingleResult();        

    }

    void taskB(){
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("callStoreProcedure2"); 

        if(query.execute())
            query.getSingleResult();                    
    }
}
```

Every time the second task is running it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed`. Looks like the first task is closing the entityManager. How can I avoid this without changing @PersistenceContext annotation?

Full stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getMaxResults(AbstractProducedQuery.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getResultList(ProcedureCallImpl.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getSingleResult(ProcedureCallImpl.java:744) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:374) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl.taskA(TaskServiceImpl.java:602) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl....(TaskServiceImpl.java:112) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl....(TaskServiceImpl.java:163) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.test.schedule.ScheduledTask.scheduledTaskA(ScheduledTask.java:45) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: Add @Stateful on class header

Comment: I checked the code. For me it works.

Comment: You are using `entityManager` which automatically may not have an open connection. Are you using your entitymanager elsewhere ??. `@PersistenceContext` means the entitymanager is directly managed by spring/jpa. You may have closed this somewhere else.

Comment: @Acewin the connection is open but when executing `query.getSingleResult()`  throws the error

Comment: @Patrick if you run it manually it works but when you use scheduler it throws the error.

Comment: @tangobee I run it by using the scheduler. I think if you post the "full" or more code we will see maybe some other issue.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error because if the offered solutions are not working for you, then the issue is not that straightforward

Comment: I agree with @UroshT. the issue may not be straightforward.  If you could post the full stack trace or your code repo to github for review. Additional information will be helpful.

Comment: @Patrick full stack trace included

Comment: @tangobee can you specify those three lines in your code: `com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl.taskA(TaskServiceImpl.java:602) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl....(TaskServiceImpl.java:112) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.test.service.TaskServiceImpl....(TaskServiceImpl.java:163) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to run the StoredProcedureQuery(s) in a transactional context.  Please try adding @Transactional to each of your methods.

```
@Transactional
void taskA(){
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("callStoreProcedure1"); 

    if(query.execute()) 
        query.getSingleResult();        

}

@Transactional
void taskB(){
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("callStoreProcedure2"); 

    if(query.execute())
        query.getSingleResult();                    
}
```

You might also want to set the propagation to new to insure these each run within their own separate transaction @Tansacational(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to share same entity manager. Which is short living object.

You can apply following two solutions :

1) Inject EntityManagerFactory and inside of EntityManager, in method use factory to create EntityManager.

```
  @PersistenceUnit(unitName= "em")
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

2) Create two different services let each service have there own entity manger instance.
  (Not sure it will work second time when method will called by scheduler. Test it and let me know.)